# Filtering based on metadata_storage_path Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I want to filter results based on a specific path for example "/container/folder1", however I am using metadata_storage_path as my document key hence it is encrypted as base64 by default.
I have tried to create the filter based on the encrypted value but that doesn't seem to work, example    `"filter": "metadata_storage_path eq 'aHR0cHM6Ly9hemRdasb2IuYmxvYi5jb3JdpbmRvd3sL3NlYXJjaddkZXIsad=='",`. I suppose it's because of the special characters that the base64encoded path contains.
Is there a way to filter based on this base 64 encoded metadata path ?
I have also tried using the base64decode function, and mapping the metadata storage path to a decoded field using fieldmapping but it returns an error every time I re-run the indexer, looks like the document key cannot actually be decoded.
Any help would be appreciated.

Errors I get when using the base64decode function.

```
'metadata_storage_path': The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. '
```

Comment: When I try to decode the value, I get the following back: `https://azd]j"&"6%[6V&6vFW"Ɲ` which does not look right to me.

Comment: I modified the encoded base 64 value with random characters just not to put my real blob url in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message , you should check if the length of base64string is a multiple of 4 and the base64string is valid .

A Base64 string will only be composed of characters `'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '+', '/'` and it is often padded at the end with up to two **'='**, to make the length a multiple of 4.

Your original base64string length is 62, not a multiple of 4, you should delete the last two **"="** padding character to make the base64string valid .

Comment: Thanks! the == is what was causing the filter not to properly work